# getArrayResult give duplicate result

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony project and try to get some result from my BDD
So what I'm doing is :

```
$result1 = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
->leftJoin('p.payments','payments')
->select('p.id, payments.name')
->getQuery()
->getArrayResult();
return $result1;
```

In my entity I have :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RB\OrdersBundle\Entity\Payment",mappedBy="purchase",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $payments;
```

and in my payment entity :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RB\OrdersBundle\Entity\Purchase")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $purchase;
```

**What I have :**
A purchase can have multiple payment. And my request give me as many result as the number of payment. exemple :

```
[
    { 
        "id" : 1
        "name" : "name1"
    }
    { 
        "id" : 1
        "name" : "name2"
    }
]
```

**What I want :**
I want a single result with an array of payment name like that :

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1
        "name": ["name1","name2"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not actually an "Array Result", you just want to use another "Hydration mode" than the normal one, that takes a lot of time.

Try this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

...

$query = $em->getRepository('YourRepo')
                ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->innerJoin('p.payments','payments')
                ->addSelect('payments')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

More information on the documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html